# How does "load_dataset" work, as it is not detecting example files?

Tags: python, pandas, github, seaborn, read.csv

I´m learning about the seaborn package in Datacamp and one of the files that include in the documentation is "tips.csv", which belongs to the repository [https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data][1] that I have found in other posts.

I´m trying to load the dataset "tips.csv" on VSCode but it raises the following error:

````
ValueError: 'tips.csv' is not one of the example datasets.```


  [1]: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data

> How can I solve this, as it is available in the link provided? I think
> it is not detecting the website, but I have internet connection.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you got confused by the docs :

> *Parameters*
>
> `name` str:
> Name of the dataset (`{name}.csv` on https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data).

The [`dataset_names`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.get_dataset_names.html#seaborn.get_dataset_names) actually don't have a *suffix*. So, you should write `tips` and not `tips.csv` :

```
print(sns.get_dataset_names())

[
    'anagrams',
    'anscombe',
    'attention',
    ...
    'taxis',
    'tips', # <-- here is yours
    'titanic'
]

df = sns.load_dataset("tips")
```

Output :

```
print(df)

     total_bill  tip     sex smoker   day    time  size
0         16.99 1.01  Female     No   Sun  Dinner     2
1         10.34 1.66    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     3
2         21.01 3.50    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     3
3         23.68 3.31    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     2
..          ...  ...     ...    ...   ...     ...   ...
240       27.18 2.00  Female    Yes   Sat  Dinner     2
241       22.67 2.00    Male    Yes   Sat  Dinner     2
242       17.82 1.75    Male     No   Sat  Dinner     2
243       18.78 3.00  Female     No  Thur  Dinner     2

[244 rows x 7 columns]
```